# Route: product.show URI: {lang}/product/{id} Missing parameter: lang

Tags: php, routes, laravel-8, multilingual

1 : website is complete (ready to set languages {Middleware and kernel is set }).

2 : all the routes set correctly and checked it to many times and no problem with view and variable.

3 : I don't want use sessions so don't try that way {if any solution with my way, I'll appreciate} .

4 : I used Group and want to use Prefix for localization process...

so its my code and I'm getting this error

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: product.show] [URI: {lang}/product/{id}] [Missing parameter: lang]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\shopers\laravel\resources\views\home.blade.php)

for information : there is no missing with routs in home.blade.php and I did check many ways one of them is string like ( 'fa' ) means Farsi and website worked perfect so there was no error !

```
Route::group([ 'middleware'=>['language','navbar'] , 'prefix'=>'{lang}' ], function($lang) {

    Route::get('/',    [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::get('/page/{id}/{slug?}',                            [\App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class,'show'])->name('page.show');
    Route::post('basket/add/{id}',                              [\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class,'basket_add'])->name('basket.add.item');

});
```

so this is some of my code you need to know my codding !...
Can you explain why lang's variable missing ??

for fix this please write correct code !

thanks for taking your valuable time .

Comment: What code is triggering that error? With the way you have your code defined, any time you call the `url()` or `route()` function, you'll need to pass a `lang` param, like `route('page.show', ['lang' => 'en', 'id' => '1', 'slug' => 'one'])` (as an example); the `'lang' => 'en'` (or `'fa'`, etc.) is required on **all** routes. Why don't you want to use Sessions? Laravel has code to manage its own session logic, and makes localization _much_ easier when used. You might want to re-think your approach to this, or figure out a way to manage `'lang' => ...` on each request.

Comment: I know how can manage lang variable ... { in middleware send prefix to views( .blade.php ) and put it in routs }
so is there any solution means easy way ... ? 
why not session ? I don't trust ... so if it's reasonable I'll think about it .
your guess is true. and you know what is the problem about error .

Answer (score 0):

Routes is up there .

How it's work to me with my rules !

put this code in one middlleware that's manage languages things

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $lang = $request->segment(1) ;
        if( $lang == 'fa' || $lang == 'en' )
        {
            URL::defaults(['lang' => $lang]);
            App::setLocale($lang);
            $language = Language::where('slug',$lang)->first();
            $request ->attributes->add(['language' => $language]);
            view()->share('language',$language);
        }
        else
        {
            abort(404);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Home will work perfect but you need manage functions
Example code for manage pages :

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    //
    function show (Request $request , $lang , $id)
    {
        $language = $request ->attributes->get('language' );
        $page     = PageContent::where(['language_id'=>$language->id ,'id'=>$id])->firstOrFail();

        return view('page-show',compact('page'));
    }
}
```

You need manage Database for languages like

Pages : id  , title ,text , slugs ...

```
    1   , contact us  , bla bla , contact_us
```

languages : id , title , direction , slug

```
        1  , farsi , right , fa

        2  , english , left , en
```

Page_contents :  id , language_id ,  page_id , title , text , ...

```
             1  , 2           ,  1   ,   contact us , bla bla , ...
 
             2  , 1           ,  1   ,   تماس با ما    ,  bla bla farsi things , ...
```

It's my  personal experience and you can do it without sessions ! 100% worked And checked with 2 languages farsi and english .